# FFMPEG: Invalid data found when processing input

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, video-streaming, audio-streaming

I want to use mp3 stream as an audio to video stream using ffmpeg. Here is audio stream: http://nspj.radiozamosc.pl/ It worked really well until today. I have no idea why it stopped working as audio stream seems to be fine (however I have no controll over it), but ffprobe cannot process it (`Invalid data found when processing input`).

The same error appears in stream log:
`[AVIOContext @ 0x21a7280] Statistics: 2521 bytes read, 0 seeks http://nspj.radiozamosc.pl/: Invalid data found when processing input`

Why it doesn't work anymore? Is it possible to fix it?

Comment: `ffmpeg -i "http://nspj.radiozamosc.pl/" out.mp3` is working fine for me, although the stream on the link you've provided only contains white noise.

Comment: White noise is ok for the moment. What ffmpeg version do you have? Do you think that i have to recompile newer version of ffmpeg?

Comment: Tested successfully on both `4.1.8-0+deb10u1` and `version n5.0`

Comment: You might want to define your interpretation of "doesn't work", as it is the same as saying "my car doesn't work". It is impossible to guess a root problem based from that statement. Please also add console output to your question using the appropriate code tags (`{}`)

Comment: I have `3.4.8-0ubuntu0.2`. Maybe it is a bit old. I wonder what happened as it stopped working overnight after more than one year. `ffprobe http://nspj.radiozamosc.pl/` provide such output `http://nspj.radiozamosc.pl: Invalid data found when processing input`.

Comment: Well, updating could maybe solve the issue, your version is 5 years old.

Answer (score -1):

I am managing this stream for my friend. It turned out that he was late with paying the internet bill and all `http` requests sent back html page with reminder about the payment (other protocols like `ssh` or `rtmp` were not affected at all). That is why `ffmpeg` could not process that particular audio stream.

Thanks for your assistance.